# In for loop, I want to get array every time

Tags: c, loops, pointers, duplicates

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(void)
{
srand(time(NULL));
int answer;
int treatment = rand() % 4;
printf("###발모제 찾기###\n\n");

int cntShowBottle = 0;
int prevCntShowBottle = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <=3; i++)
{
    int bottle[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int* ptr = bottle;
    do {
        cntShowBottle = rand() % 2 + 2;
    } while (cntShowBottle == prevCntShowBottle);
    prevCntShowBottle == cntShowBottle;

    int isincluded = 0;
    printf(" %d 번째 시도 : ", i);

        for (int j = 0; j < cntShowBottle; j++)
        {
            int randBottle = rand() % 4;

            if (bottle[randBottle] == 0)
            {
                bottle[randBottle] = 1;
                if (randBottle == treatment)
                {
                    isincluded = 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                j--;
            }
        }
```

I want to get different array 'bottle[]' every time like {0,1,1,0},{1,1,1,0},{1,1,0,1} without duplication.. I think it needs (do while) and (pointer), but I don't know how to coding.

Comment: After `do while` the line with `prevCntShowBottle == cntShowBottle;` looks like a bug; it does nothing.

Comment: `prevCntShowBottle == cntShowBottle;`? Do you mean to use *assignment* as in `prevCntShowBottle = cntShowBottle;`? That problem should have been easy to find out with a *debugger*.

Comment: As for the problem of generating three different arrays, perhaps you should do it as a separate step before the main loop, and actually create three different arrays (like `int bottles[3][4];`)? Then you can generate one after the other and make sure none is a duplicate of the previous arrays (do the generating loop again if `memcmp` to previous arrays indicates that they are the same).